# Can't adjust trackpoint speed on Lenovo T450s with 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad, lenovo, trackpoint

I've been trying to adjust the speed of the trackpoint speed in 18.04 but I have had no success. I've tried changing mouse speed in Settings app but nothing changes even with the touchpad I never use. In gnome-tweaks I tried adjusting a setting called acceleration profile to Adaptive and it does make it faster but it enables mouse acceleration which I don't want. I've searched online and seen mentions of editing props in `xinput` but `list` doesn't show my trackpoint even though its working fine

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

How do I change it and get it to stick after reboots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Device id=11 is covering both touchpad and trackpoint.

I had similar issue on Dell and xinput helped me.

First do `xinput --list-props 11`, it will show you properties of that device.
Then find the property you want to change and change it with (this is my case, yours will be different)

`xinput set-prop "DualPoint Stick" "libinput Accel Speed" -0.5`

where "DualPoint Stick" is name of the device (Ps/2 Synaptic Touchpad in your case) and libintput accel speed is name of property I wanted to change.

Then I put this commmand to ~/.xinitrc and it is applied automatically.

Note - don't use deivce number in the command, but rather use device name, because ID can change when you connect other peripherals.

Comment: That worked for me. It's much better now. Thanks! Is there anyway to set it more than 1?

Comment: Nope. According to man libinput

Option "AccelSpeed" "float"
              Sets the pointer acceleration speed within the range [-1, 1]

Comment: Understood, at least it's way better than before. Thanks again.

Comment: Saving the commands to `~/xinitrc` didn't make the changes persist after restarts for me, but putting them in `~/.xsessionrc` did.

Comment: On my x1 carbon 6th running 19.04 this seems to be fixed, gnome settings display speed for mouse and for touchpad, and xinput lists them as different devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had this Problem with a new Thinkpad L580 (maybe the same is for L480, t480,t580) with Ubuntu 18.04 and found the solution in [this reddit][https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/4jku4c/configuring_trackpoint_on_thinkpad_13/d3asw6g/]

1) remove libinput **BUT ATTENTION!!!** it is very likely, that you **can't input anything afterwards**, so you have to have the possibility to ssh into the machine

`sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput` (ubuntu 18 will remove "xserver-xorg-input-libinput-all")

2) maybe execute this first!
 install evdev (if your debian/ubuntu doesn't fall back to it automatically)
`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev`

3) work with xinput, like:
`xinput set-prop 'device-name-or-number' "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 0.2`
the lower this value, the faster the TrackPoint will be, so try with 0.5 and work your way down or up